# Roadmap for functionality with office.js in PowerPoint

Tags: office-js

Is there a roadmap on extending office.js for PowerPoint? Would be nice to be able to interact with the elements on a slide. As a possibly quicker route if you enabled Office.CoercionType.Ooxml for more apps other than Word we could parse and manipulate the data ourselves.

The current PowerPoint capabilities for inserting text/images is very limited. My specific scenario is to move an old VSTO plugin over to the add-in model, where I iterate all text elements and look at the metadata.

Comment: do you know if this type of functionality now exists in officejs powerpoint? I couldnt find anything.

Comment: v1.5 added more capabilities which may help your scenario https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/powerpoint/powerpoint-api-requirement-sets?view=common-js-preview#powerpoint-javascript-api-15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not, PowerPoint has not provided a open specification along the lines of Excel or Word at this time.

I would strongly suggest posting your suggestions and blockers into the [User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). For blocking issues, please be sure and note that this is blocking migration from VSTO. This information invaluable when it comes time to prioritize items on the roadmap.

Comment: Thank you, and I've added this as an idea.